# Getting list of layer names using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, list, layer-name

I need a list containing the names of all the layers in a QGIS session. I did the task as

```py
layersNames = []
for i in self.iface.mapCanvas().layers():
   layersNames.append(str(i.name()))
```

but this has the problem that only the names for the visible layers are extracted. How can I get a list with the names of all (visible or not) layers using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()` will give you all layers that are opened.

If you want the names then:

```py
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
```

`names` will be a list of layer names

or using a normal function:

```py
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    print layer.name()
```

Comment: Is there any way of listing down the layers from qgis project (.qgz) by mentioning the filename ? in other words, I want to loop over list of files and list down all the layers ?

Answer (score 29):

Since version 3, `QgsMapLayerRegistry` funcionalities have been moved to `QgsProject`: https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html

### Update for QGIS3.x:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print(names)
```

as per [@Nathan W's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118865/99589), this produces a list of layers in the current project:

```
['GoogleSat', 'MyPointsLayer', 'Roads', 'House_numbers']
```

Comment: How does it work in the new version to get back just active layers?