# Getting a layer that is not active with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-2

I want to retrieve attributes of selected objects on a layer with PyQGIS.
All example I see is for the active layer:

```
vlayer=qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
selected_bf = vlayer.selectedFeatures()
```

But, my features are not on the active layer. What is the way to say that vlayer is another layer but not the active layer?

---

I put this:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import * 
vlayer = processing.getObject('mylayer')
selected_objects = vlayer.selectedFeatures()
```

as a filter expression in QGIS 2.8 but I can't open QGIS after.

`Error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'selectedFeatures'"`

Answer (score 7):

You can also reference a layer by it's name:

```
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName("MY_LAYER_NAME")[0]
selected = layer.selectedFeatures()
```

if your not sure of the name, you can look for it:

```
layer=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() == "MY_LAYER_NAME":
        layer = lyr
        break
```

Note for QGIS 3.x: in QGIS3 you should replace `QgsMapLayerRegistry` by `QgsProject` (see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/340288/147426)).

Comment: But now, I can't open QGIS (I have this as an expression filter). Error: "Name 'QgsMapLayerRegistry' is not defined".

Answer (score 5):

Look at [Get a list of layer names using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118862/get-a-list-of-layer-names-using-pyqgis)`

You can use a simple Python dictionary

```
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()]
layers = dict((name,i) for i, name in enumerate(names))
print layers
{u'layer1': 1, u'layer2': 0, u'layer3': 2, u'layer': 3, ...}
```

or:

```
canvas= qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
layers = dict((k.name(),i) for i, k in enumerate(canvas.layers()))
print layers
{u'layer1': 1, u'layer2': 0, u'layer3': 2, u'layer': 3, ...}
```

And to select the layer:

```
layer1 = canvas.layer(layers['layer1'])
layer2 = canvas.layer(layers['layer2'])
....
# or
layer1 = canvas.layer(1)
layer2 = canvas.layer(2)
....
```

But if you add a new layer, you must start over, not with the `processing` module:

```
import processing
layer1 = processing.getObject('layer1')
layerx =  processing.getObject('newlayer')
```