# Looking for QGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "List By Data Source"

Tags: qgis, layers, qgs

I have a client with many duplicates and redundant layers, we are going through the folders and deleting archiving files.

In ArcGIS Desktop, I select 'List By Data Source' to find out what layers a project contains.

How do I do that in QGIS?

Comment: in PyQGIS : `print(", ".join([lyr.name() for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers()])`

Comment: So my only answer is to do it programmatically? I hope not, many of the guys doing this work have no programming skills. Also it looks like a bot edited my post, now I have poor grammar. Also thanks for the reply!

Comment: I posted it as a comment for you if you needed that without request, for those who are interested and get here, but not as an answer because you didn't talk about Python or code.

Comment: Thank you! I might just have to do it myself via python it seems.

Comment: [ChangeDataSource](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/) plugin gives you the option to see the layer names and their data sources (folder tree). Maybe this is not exactly what you need, but at least it shows the data source for every layer for quick investigation.

Comment: @J.Monticolo may refer to this thread : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150611/getting-list-of-layers-names-using-pyqgis/150630#150630

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Layer board plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/LayerBoard/). You can also export to csv file.

Answer (score 3):

There is a native QGIS processing tool "Export Layer(s) information" which should do the task.

[image]