# Listing loaded layers in QGIS with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, layers, qgsmapcanvas

I've stuck on a issue about getting a list of loaded layers. I've two layers loaded, one spatial (point, line or area) and another one non spatial (PostgreSQL table).

I've tried this code but it lists only the spatial layers:

```py
layername = []

for i in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
    layername.append(i.name())

print(layername)
```

I've tried `QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()`

```py
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
ids = root.findLayerIds()
print(ids)
```

but it gives me a layer name plus an id.

How can I get a list of layer names from all loaded layers (spatial and non-spatial) in QGIS 3?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @FranciscoCamello! The same method can be used from the post [Get a list of layer names using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118862/get-a-list-of-layer-names-using-pyqgis) (albeit it is old but the answer is still valid): `layers = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try

```py
layerList = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()
for layer in layerList:
    print(layer.name())
```

That will give you a list of layer names

Check out the [`QgsLayerTree`](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTree.html) class for more info

Comment: Thanks @Tim its solve my problem. I've also tried with layerTreeRoot().findLayersIds() but it gives the name plus id